# Custom color palette for plot_likert function from sjPlot

Tags: r, plot, sjplot, likert

I can plot with following data using `plot_likert` function from `sjPlot` `R` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <-
  data.frame(
  matrix(
    data = sample(x = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), size = 500, replace = TRUE),
    ncol = 5
    )
  ) %>% 
  mutate_all(., ~ ordered(., levels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")))

df1
library(sjPlot)
plot_likert(
   items       = df1
  , cat.neutral = 3
  )
```

[image]

I wonder how to get the following color scheme:

```
Strongly Disagree = Dark Red
Disagree          = Light Red
Neutral           = Gray
Agree             = Light Green
Strongly Agree    = Dark Green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your desired colors via the arguments `geom.colors` and `cat.neutral.color`:

Note: As R has no color named `lightred` I switched to `firebrick1`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sjPlot)

df1 <- data.frame(
    matrix(
      data = sample(x = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), size = 500, replace = TRUE),
      ncol = 5
    )
  ) %>% 
  mutate_all(., ~ ordered(., levels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")))

plot_likert(items = df1, cat.neutral = 3, 
            geom.colors = c("darkred", "firebrick1", "lightgreen", "darkgreen"),
            cat.neutral.color = "gray")
```

[image]